# How to restrict Android.mk to compile a module to generate only 64bit library

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-build

I am able to integarte a 64 bit prebuilt library "x" in android for arm platform and when i try calling that libary in required module which will compile for both 32bit and 64bit library failed mentioning 32 bit library of "x" is not found.
/out/target/product/xxxx/system/lib64/libxxxx.so

1. prebuilt library makefile

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libfoo.so
    LOCAL_MODULE := libfoo
    LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .so
    LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARIES
    LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT)/lib64
    LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := debug
    LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
    include $(BUILD_PREBUILT
```

2. Linking module Makefile

```
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
        test.c 
        
    LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
        liblog \
        libcutils 

    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

    ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH),arm64)
       LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES   += libfoo.so
    endif

    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wall -Werror 
    LOCAL_MODULE := vtest
    LOCAL_MODULE_RELATIVE_PATH := test
    LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

```
ninja: error: 'out/target/product/xxxx/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libxxxx_intermediates/export_includes', needed by 'out/target/product/xxxx/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/yyyyy/import_includes', missing and no known rule to make it
```

i want to restrict the linking module to build only for 64 bit not for 32 bit, i tried following but not working
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH),arm64)
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libxxx
endif

Please provide suggestions to resolve this issue

Comment: Please edit your question and add an entire makefile that reproduces the behavior you describe.

Comment: @Michael i have added the makefile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last fixed by following changes  and it worked

```
LOCAL_MODULE_TARGET_ARCH := arm64
LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/libfoo.so
```

instead of

```
 ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH),arm64)
   LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES   += libfoo.so
endif
```

@maurice you are partially correct thanks for your input its LOCAL_LDLIBS helped along with Target Arch

Answer (score 1):

From https://source.android.com/setup/develop/64-bit-builds :

`LOCAL_MODULE_TARGET_ARCH`

Set this variable to a list of architectures, such as `arm x86 arm64`. If the architecture being built is in that list, the current module is included by the build system.

`LOCAL_MODULE_UNSUPPORTED_TARGET_ARCH`

This variable is the opposite of `LOCAL_MODULE_TARGET_ARCH`. If the architecture being built is not in that list, the current module is included by the build system.

Comment: i verified already by placing LOCAL_MODULE_TARGET_ARCH as arm64 , still facing same issue its looking for 32 bit library as well during compilation

Comment: Is the error message still the same? Because the target you are building is in `out/target/product/xxxx/obj_arm`, if you set the TARGET_ARCH correctly it should not try to build that anymore

Comment: In case that wasn't clear, you need specify the TARGET_ARCH in both the prebuilt (`libfoo`) and the `vtest`