# C/C++: ld: error: found local symbol '__bss_start' in global part of symbol table in file

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I am creating a project in android studio with using opencv library. my ndk is r23 and my cmake is 3.18.1.
this is my graddle.build(app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.slam3'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.slam3"
        minSdk 29
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags '-std=c++11'
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
            version '3.18.1'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation project(path: ':openCV')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

i use CMakeLists.txt for using a simple native lib in my project. my CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(pathToProject C:/Users/HYPER_STOCK_TABRIZ/AndroidStudioProjects/Slam3)
set(pathToOpenCV C:/Users/HYPER_STOCK_TABRIZ/AndroidStudioProjects/OpenCV-android-sdk)

#For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.1)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

include_directories(${pathToOpenCV}/sdk/native/jni/include)


# Declares and names the project.

project("slam3")

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        slam3

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        native-lib.cpp)

add_library(lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${pathToProject}/app/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log)

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries(slam3 ${log-lib} lib_opencv)
```

When i run project in device i see this error:

```
C/C++: ld: error: found local symbol '__bss_start' in global part of symbol table in file C:/Users/HYPER_STOCK_TABRIZ/AndroidStudioProjects/Slam3/app/src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopencv_java3.so
```

i test [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55014879/local-symbol-bss-start-in-global-part-of-symbol-table-only-in-android-ndk)

but still i has the same error. how can i solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["local symbol '\_\_bss\_start' in global part of symbol table" only in Android NDK aarch64 build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55014879/local-symbol-bss-start-in-global-part-of-symbol-table-only-in-android-ndk)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using different ndk version.
In my case,I changed the ndkVersion to 21.4.7075529 and the problem is solved.

**build.gradle**

```
android {
 compileSdk = 33
 ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
 ....
}
```