# found local symbol '__end__' in global part of symbol table in file With pytorch in android studio

Tags: cmake, pytorch, java-native-interface, build.gradle

Ive been trying for a good bit of time now and can't seem to find a solution to my problem anyhere on here seems like its an error caussed by the Arm64-v8a jni.
This is the build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
    }

}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.digitalwhiteboard'
    configurations {
        extractForNativeBuild
    }
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion "34.0.0-rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.digitalwhiteboard"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared" ,
                    "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=ON",
                    "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang",
                    "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-29",
                    "-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=rtti exceptions",
                    "-DANDROID_NDK=C:/Users/Kure/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653",
                    "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release",
                    "-Wl,--gc-sections"
                cFlags "-fstack-protector-all", "-fvisibility=hidden", "-ffunction-sections", "-fdata-sections"
                cppFlags "-std=c++17", "-fstack-protector-all", "-fvisibility=hidden", "-ffunction-sections", "-fdata-sections"
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            //path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
            path "./CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
        }
    }
    ndkVersion '25.2.9519653'
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        //exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libpytorch_jni.so'
        //exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so'
        //exclude 'lib/x86_64/libnative-lib.so'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    //CameraX
    def camerax_version = "1.3.0-alpha04"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:${camerax_version}"

    //PyTorch
    def pyTorchVersion = "1.12.2"
    implementation "org.pytorch:pytorch_android:${pyTorchVersion}"
    implementation "org.pytorch:pytorch_android_torchvision:${pyTorchVersion}"
    extractForNativeBuild "org.pytorch:pytorch_android:${pyTorchVersion}"
}

task extractAARForNativeBuild {
    doLast {
        configurations.extractForNativeBuild.files.each {
            def file = it.absoluteFile
            copy {
                from zipTree(file)
                into "$buildDir/$file.name"
                include "headers/**"
                include "jni/**"
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.contains('externalNativeBuild')) {
        task.dependsOn(extractAARForNativeBuild)
    }
}
```

and this is my Cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)
set(TARGET cppNativeFiles)
project(${TARGET} CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(build_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build)


set(pytorch_testapp_cpp_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/main/cpp)
file(GLOB SOURCES
        ${pytorch_testapp_cpp_DIR}/cppNative.cpp
    )
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES src/main/cpp/*.cpp)

add_library(${TARGET} SHARED
    src/main/cpp/cppNative.cpp
    )


file(GLOB PYTORCH_INCLUDE_DIRS "${build_DIR}/pytorch_android*.aar/headers")
file(GLOB PYTORCH_LINK_DIRS "${build_DIR}/pytorch_android*.aar/jni/${ANDROID_ABI}")
#message(WARNING "<PYTORCH_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${PYTORCH_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
#message(WARNING "<PYTORCH_LINK_DIRS: ${PYTORCH_LINK_DIRS}")

target_compile_options(${TARGET} PRIVATE
    -fexceptions
    )

set(BUILD_SUBDIR ${ANDROID_ABI})

find_library(PYTORCH_LIBRARY pytorch_jni
    PATHS ${PYTORCH_LINK_DIRS}
    NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH)
#find_library(FBJNI_LIBRARY fbjni
#    PATHS ${PYTORCH_LINK_DIRS}
#    NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH)

set(OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIR "${OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK}/sdk/native/jni/include")

target_include_directories(${TARGET} PRIVATE
    "${OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIR}"
    ${PYTORCH_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(OPENCV_LIB_DIR "${OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK}/sdk/native/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}")

find_library(OPENCV_LIBRARY opencv_java4
    PATHS ${OPENCV_LIB_DIR}
    NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH)


find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
    log-lib
    # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
    # you want CMake to locate.
    log)

find_library(jnigraphics-lib jnigraphics)

target_link_libraries(${TARGET}
    #myLibary
    ${PYTORCH_LIBRARY}
    #${FBJNI_LIBRARY}
    ${OPENCV_LIBRARY}
    ${jnigraphics-lib}
    ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}
    ${log-lib})
```

Have tried most compile options i could find online to fix the issue. Seems like it's the arm64-v8a used globad symbolsthe other pytorch jni's use as loical and that gives the issue.

I have tried most things i can find online and even tried my luck with Chat-gtp, but still no luck. Im kinda out of ideas and don't know what can solve the issue now. My supervoiser at Uni can't seem to find the issue either.

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55014879/11107541